# MQTT JavaScript client not connecting (wrong protocol?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, mqtt

I am trying really hard to make my MQTT client work inside my application. The broker is provided by [CloudMQTT](http://www.cloudmqtt.com).

When trying to run the following code in NodeJS, the client connects properly to MQTT;

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client = mqtt.connect(
        "mqtt://m20.cloudmqtt.com",
        {
            port: 11212,
            username: "XXXXXXXX",
            password: "XXXXXXXX"
        }
);

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
});
```

However, when I run the same code (without the require of course) in the frontend using [the Bower package](https://github.com/reitzemaj/mqttjs-browserified), the client does not connect. I have also tried other MQTT browserfied JS packages. I prefer MQTT.js and not Paho, because I would like to use multiple subscribes with one connected client.

If `console.log(client);`, NodeJS uses `protocol: 'mqtt'` and `protocolId: 'MQTT'`. The frontend uses `protocol: 'ws'` and `protocolId: 'MQTT'`. Could this be the problem? Adding these options to mqtt.connect has no effect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about multiple subscribes with the PAHO client. You can subscribe to multiple topics with the PAHO client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From with in the browser the only option is going to be to connect via MQTT over Websockets. CloudMQTT use different port numbers for native MQTT and MQTT over websockets so you will need to also change the port number for the browser based code to the Websocket port listed in your CloudMQTT dashboard.

Comment: The websockets port is 31212. However, the CloudMQTT dashboard says "Websockets Port (TLS only)". I'm using NodeJS locally, is there a way I could make this work?

Comment: This actually did work, I managed to create a self-signed SSL certificate in MAMP and this got the websockets of CloudMQTT working. Thanks!